# Como puedo dejar de repetir el onTouchListener

Tags: android

Estoy llevando un curso online para crear apps, tengo este código que toca dos sonidos, los toca mientras se mantenga presionada la imagen correspondiente a cada sonido, en este código repito dos veces el onTouchListener, hay alguna forma de hacer algo más elegante, gracias.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ImageView imageViewSoundA = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sounda);

    imageViewSoundA.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sounda);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            }
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.reset();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    final ImageView imageViewSoundB = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.soundb);

    imageViewSoundB.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.soundb);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            }
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.reset();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sí, se puede sacar fuera ese código repetido. Además se puede simplificar un poco gracias a java 8:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.sounda).setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> handleTouchEvent(event,R.raw.sounda));
    findViewById(R.id.soundb).setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> handleTouchEvent(event,R.raw.soundb));
}

private boolean handleTouchEvent(MotionEvent event,@IdRes int soundResource)
{
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, soundResource);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    }
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        if (mediaPlayer!=null) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Cuando escribo     findViewById(R.id.soundb).setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> handleTouchEvent(event,R.raw.soundb)); me pide un entero.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes evitar definir el onTouchListener pero lo que realiza cada botón debes definirlo, en este caso define una variable para el onTouchListener :

```
private View.OnTouchListener userTouchListener = null;
```

ahora dentro de `onCreate()` define el listener:

```
    userTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

         ...
         ...

        }
    };
```

y dentro define el proceso que realizará cada botón el cual se define mediante la comparación del id de la vista :

```
    userTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

           if(view.getId() ==  R.id.sounda){

           ...
           ...

           }else if(view.getId() ==  R.id.soundb){ 

           ...
           ...

           }


        }
    };
```

---

finalmente, este sería el listener con las acciones de cada botón:

```
    userTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
             if(view.getId() ==  R.id.sounda){  //imageViewSoundA
                 if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                     mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sounda);
                     mediaPlayer.start();
                     mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                 }
                 if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                     mediaPlayer.stop();
                     mediaPlayer.reset();
                 }
                 return true;
             }else if(view.getId() ==  R.id.soundb){ //imageViewSoundB
                 if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                     mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.soundb);
                     mediaPlayer.start();
                     mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                 }
                 if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                     mediaPlayer.stop();
                     mediaPlayer.reset();
                 }
                 return true;
             }

            return false;
        }
    };
```

no olvides asignar el listener que creaste para los botónes, si tienes más botones puedes asignarle el mismo listener no olvidando definir la acción que realizará esto dentro del método `onTouch()` :

```
    imageViewSoundA.setOnTouchListener(userTouchListener);
    imageViewSoundB.setOnTouchListener(userTouchListener);
```

Comment: Esta respuesta en realidad queda bastante parecida al código mío en el sentido de repetir código, aunque mejora el uso del OnTouchListener.

Comment: Hola Rodrigo, como comentaba, el listener no lo repites, pero el código relacionado a cada botón lo tienes que agregar tal y como esta en tu pregunta ya que carga en el MediaPlayer un audio diferente (sounda y soundb).